# Neo4j and java: What does this error "NULL is not a keyed collection" mean?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I tried to delete a relationship, and this little-documented error shows up.

The query:

```
MATCH ()-[r:SendTo]-(n:Wallet)
WHERE NOT ()-[:BelongTo]->(n)
DELETE r
RETURN r
```

The whole error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.value.NotMultiValued: NULL is not a keyed collection
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.ValueAdapter.get(ValueAdapter.java:192)
at basicANeo4j.Importer.<init>(Importer.java:213)
at basicANeo4j.Importer.main(Importer.java:246)
```

When I checked the corresponding relationship, there is no property of it which is null:

```
<id>:595 value_bitcoin:20000000000outputIndex:defaultuniqueReferenceTran:bcaeee45968b5a08c88ed7a0d90a1275728eda356013465408197e9f77c634daNULLtranHashString:bcaeee45968b5a08c88ed7a0d90a1275728eda356013465408197e9f77c634datime:2016-01-01T22:55:26type:pubkeyhashvalue_dollar:86554.0estChanAddr:3KgtbGgaX2ngstNpvyv7LwpHSweVeqGbpM
```

I looked into ValueAdapter.class, this is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public Value get( String key )
{
    throw new NotMultiValued( type().name() + " is not a keyed collection" );
}
```

Without any documentation, it does not help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized where the error of keyed collection come from: while iterating through the records, I tried to print a property of the relationship, while the property does not exist for this relatioship. (I copied it from another part of my code without checking it and was convinced that it is the query which is the problem. So I missed that.)

Answer (score 3):

As Tomaz says, this is because you can't return a node or relationship you just deleted.

However, you can get a map "snapshot" of a node or relationship, delete the node or relationship, then return the snapshot.

Here's the [article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/updating-a-node-but-returning-its-state-from-before-the-update/) in the knowledge base.

Comment: I just tried without delete: MATCH ()-[r:SendTo]->(n:Wallet) WHERE NOT ()-[r:BelongTo]->(n) RETURN r. Still does not work (same error). The reason why it was brought to my attention is due to the fact that when one node should be deleted, it could not be deleted as the relationship associated with the node is not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are trying to return a null object because you deleted it first. I would try this

```
MATCH ()-[r:SendTo]-(n:Wallet)
WHERE NOT ()-[:BelongTo]->(n)
DELETE r
RETURN 'success'
```

You can return either a string, could return n if you are interested in which wallet had relationships deleted or you could not return anything.

Comment: I just tried without delete: `MATCH ()-[r:SendTo]->(n:Wallet) WHERE NOT ()-[r:BelongTo]->(n) RETURN r`. Still does not work (same error). The reason why it was brought to my attention is due to the fact that when one node should be deleted, it could not be deleted as the relationship associated with the node is not deleted.

Comment: @Aqqqq That's a very different query. You're attempting to match `r` to two relationships of different types (:SendTo and :BelongTo). That's not possible.

Comment: You can always delete a relationship without needing to detach it first. However, when deleting nodes, you should always be using `DETACH DELETE` instead of delete alone.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried with the corrected version: `MATCH ()-[r:SendTo]->(n:Wallet) WHERE NOT ()-[:BelongTo]->(n) RETURN r`. Still same error.

Comment: @aqqqq There isn't anything wrong with that query. What version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: @InverseFalcon neo4j-enterprise 3.1.1, driver version: 1.2.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142135/discussion-between-aqqqq-and-inversefalcon).